# How to select a list's li based on text and then edit child span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="words">
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">10</span>Apple</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">50</span>Banana</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">30</span>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking for a jQuery selector that will select a list item like `Banana` and then be able to edit its child badge to whatever value.

I was looking around and saw some very complex selectors involving `contains` (which isn't exact enough for me already) and lambda functions/loops spanning multiple lines and was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: If you want a better way, add [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) attributes to your elements so you can use the data in your selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6L16nfbz/)**.

You can use **[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** like **@dsh** mentioned in comment, see the example below :

**HTML :**

```
<ul class="list-group" id="words">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-text="Apple"><span class="badge">10</span>Apple</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-text="Banana"><span class="badge">50</span>Banana</li>
    <li class="list-group-item" data-text="Carrot"><span class="badge">30</span>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

**JS :**

```
$( ".list-group-item[data-text='Banana'] .badge" ).text(); //50
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`$("li:contains(Banana)>.badge").text("whatever")`

should be the proper selector for jQuery. However, you should try to avoid :contains() if you are not specific. The selector above has to search in every list element. If you only search in the given list use

`$("#words>li:contains(Banana)>.badge").text("whatever")`

instead or use `data` Attributes, as dsh has commented,

Comment: Ah okay so `data` is much faster? What does it use, hashes or something?

Comment: I'm not sure how `data` is implemented. :contains() performs a deep search for the given string in the list element and every child element. Depending on your HTML, this search is much slower than just looking for a string in a few elements attributes.